# Poisson process for small sample size

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, extrapolation, frequency-severity

Suppose I have a data set that contains insurance claims $X$. Each claim also is assigned the calendar year during which the insured event happened. Now, I want to build a frequency/severity model but only for the extremely large claims, say $X \geq \mu$.

Assuming a homogeneous poisson process for the frequency component, the rate parameter $\lambda_{\mu}$ in the model clearly depends on the large loss threshold $\mu$ I choose. However, there may only be very few (if any) observed losses above the large loss threshold, so any estimator $\hat{\lambda}_{\mu}$ will be very unreliable due to the increasingly small sample size.

I thought of building a simple polynomial regression model for $\lambda_{\mu}$ in order to be able to extrapolate a rate parameter for very high and possibly unobserved claim sizes.

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there anything better one can do?

Comment: GEVs (generalized extreme value) models such as peak-over-threshold (POT) are appropriate in this case, particularly wrt insurance claims. There is a literal ton of papers on this method (pop these keywords into search 'peak-over-threshold models') but the bible on this subject was and continues to be Embrechts, et al., *Modeling Extremal Events* https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modelling_Extremal_Events/BXOI2pICfJUC?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: From my understanding, that is mainly used to set a threshold after which claims can be modelled using a GPD (Pickands-Balkema-de Haan). Say I managed to fit a GPD above a certain threshold, say 10^4, to model claim sizes. Now I can certainly use this model to simulate claims even much higher than this threshold and beyond anything we have observed so far, say 10^6. But because there is no data when restricted to claims greater than 10^6, how do I go about parametrising the frequency component?

Comment: The hardest part of GPDs is picking the threshold. If the choice leaves you with no data ,how can you parametrize anything? Have you explored tweedie models, as commonly used in applied claims modeling? Also, another useful tool is quantile regression which can be parametrized for any quantile.